# Laravel Unirest and Rapid Api not accepting form parameters

Tags: laravel

Intermediate programmer, but this is my first foray into using API's and RapidAPI in particular. I am using the "WorldWide Restaurants" API ( [Documentation Here](https://rapidapi.com/ptwebsolution/api/worldwide-restaurants) )

When using the example code straight from the site to access the API:

```
 $response = Unirest\Request::post("https://worldwide-restaurants.p.rapidapi.com/search",
  array(
    "X-RapidAPI-Host" => "worldwide-restaurants.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key" => "myrapidapikey",
    "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ),
  array(
    "language" => "en_US",
    "location_id" => "15333482",
    "currency" => "USD",
    "limit" => 15
  )
);
```

The Object i get back has "Validation Errors', so its not getting my second array, or i am not passing it correctly.

```
code: 200
  +raw_body: "{"status":201,"msg":"validation errors","results":["The location id field is required.","The limit field is required.","The language field is required.","The cu ▶"
  +body: {#175 ▶}
  +headers: array:16 [▶]
```

I have also tried this:

```
 $headers =  [
                'x-rapidapi-host' => 'worldwide-restaurants.p.rapidapi.com/',
                'x-rapidapi-key' => 'myrapidapikey',
                'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ];

        $data =  [
                'limit' => '30',
                'language' => 'en_US',
                'location_id' => '154913',
                'currency' => 'CAD'
            ];

        $response = Unirest\Request::post("https://worldwide-restaurants.p.rapidapi.com/search", $headers, $data);

        dd($response);
```

And have changed the name of the "data" array to everything i could think of, with the same results. I have also gone and tried to use the Guzzle laravel package, and when using that i dont get validation errors, but i also dont seem to get any usable data back.

I have a feeling i am missing a step and have searched everywhere for an answer. Hopefully someone smarter than me can see what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

EDIT: In case it matters, i am running this from WAMP on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, i ended up solving this by using the Unirest\Request\Body::form helper. Updated code below:

```
 $headers = array(
                'x-rapidapi-host' => 'worldwide-restaurants.p.rapidapi.com/',
                'x-rapidapi-key' => 'myapikey',
                'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        );

        $data = array(
                'location_id' => '154913',
                'limit' => 30,
                'language' => 'en_US',
                'currency' => 'CAD'
        );

        $body = Unirest\Request\Body::form($data);

        $response = Unirest\Request::post("https://worldwide-restaurants.p.rapidapi.com/search",
            $headers, $body);

        dd($response);
```